# Google Domains Nameserver not resolving

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I have a domain that registered on Google Domains, except I don't want to make use of their hosting options, so I've changed the nameservers to point to the hosting company's, except they don't seem to have updated worldwide yet, even though I made the change on the 27th Dec, more than enough time for the normal propagation to happen.

The domain is **alfienoakesgolf.com**, if you look at it through [who.is](https://who.is/whois/alfienoakesgolf.com) it shows that the nameservers are correct, however if you check through a [DNS nameserver checker](https://dnschecker.org/#NS/alfienoakesgolf.com) then it's coming back with only a few places that it's updated.

But it's meaning that I can't generate an FTP account or setup anything on the site until it resolves properly. I've spoken to the [hosting company - krystal.co.uk](https://krystal.co.uk/) and they said that all that should need to be done from the registrar's end is just to update the nameservers.

Is there something wrong with the Google Domains DNS as to why it's not working properly?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at https://intodns.com/alfienoakesgolf.com you will see that the nameservers are not responding for the domain so it needs to be dealt with by the hosting provider:

```
ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
The ones that did not respond are:
69.168.229.100 69.168.231.121 69.168.228.100 69.168.230.121
```

Comment: A part of me thought it must be the hosting company, there's almost nothing I can possibly do on the Google Domains page after I've changed the nameservers.